# Dynamically generate unevaluated expressions to create lagged data.frame?

Tags: r, eval, expression, plyr

I have data.frame `Z` and I would like to select only a couple of variables stored in the character vector `vars`. This of course can easily be done by:

```
Z[,vars]
```

The problem is that I need als the `lags 1 and 4`  of these variables. I use `lag(variable,-1)` to get them. I tried the following that was suggested here earlier:

```
require(plyr)
l <- c(0,1,4)
expand.grid(x=vars,l=l)
# which results in 
  x      l
var1     0
var2     0
var3     0
var1     1
var2     1
var3     1
var1     4
var2     4
var3     4

buildFaDf <- function(x,l) paste("lag(Z$",x,",-",l,")",sep="")
test <- mlply(vars,buildFaDf)
```

gives back a list of like this:

```
.... 
$`4`
[1] "lag(Z$var1,-1)"
```

If I call that list element I just get the characters back, but of course I´d like to have the data itself. In the end I want to `unlist` and end up with a data.frame containing all `vars` and their respective lags.

I also played around with `substitute` , `eval` and `expression` and could not get it done. 
Note I am not focused to the `mlply` solution here it just was suggested to me lately and I am a little biased at the moment maybe.

Comment: Maybe you can get a good solution if you provide example data and a desired output.

Comment: Thought this was more syntax problem not knowing how to use `expression` or `eval` properly, but probably data helps too. I will provide an example after lunch :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you are over-complicating the problem.  The way I see it, there are two steps to solving this:

- Step 1: Create a subset of a `data.frame` - this is trivial, and you show it in your question.
- Step 2: Create lagged variables for all columns in a `data.frame`

Here is one way of doing step 2.  I'll demonstrate with the built-in dataset `faithful`:

```
data(faithful)

dat <- head(faithful, 10)

lag1 <- function(x) c(NA, head(x, -1))
lag4 <- function(x) c(rep(NA, 4), head(x, -4))

data.frame(
  dat,
  llply(dat, lag1),
  llply(dat, lag4)
)

   eruptions waiting eruptions.1 waiting.1 eruptions.2 waiting.2
1      3.600      79          NA        NA          NA        NA
2      1.800      54       3.600        79          NA        NA
3      3.333      74       1.800        54          NA        NA
4      2.283      62       3.333        74          NA        NA
5      4.533      85       2.283        62       3.600        79
6      2.883      55       4.533        85       1.800        54
7      4.700      88       2.883        55       3.333        74
8      3.600      85       4.700        88       2.283        62
9      1.950      51       3.600        85       4.533        85
10     4.350      85       1.950        51       2.883        55
```

---

To turn the solution into a function that does the subsetting as well as lagging, do the following:

```
dat <- data.frame(head(faithful, 10), newcol=LETTERS[1:10])

laggedDF <- function(x, vars){
  lag1 <- function(x) c(NA, head(x, -1))
  lag4 <- function(x) c(rep(NA, 4), head(x, -4))
  dat <- x[, vars, drop=FALSE]
  print(dat)
  data.frame(
    dat,
    llply(dat, lag1),
    llply(dat, lag4)
  )
}

laggedDF(dat, vars=c("eruptions", "newcol"))

   eruptions newcol eruptions.1 newcol.1 eruptions.2 newcol.2
1      3.600      A          NA       NA          NA       NA
2      1.800      B       3.600        1          NA       NA
3      3.333      C       1.800        2          NA       NA
4      2.283      D       3.333        3          NA       NA
5      4.533      E       2.283        4       3.600        1
6      2.883      F       4.533        5       1.800        2
7      4.700      G       2.883        6       3.333        3
8      3.600      H       4.700        7       2.283        4
9      1.950      I       3.600        8       4.533        5
10     4.350      J       1.950        9       2.883        6
```

Comment: 1) Thx Andrie. Indeed I was overcomplicating things. Maybe this is because I am interested in general how to dynamically paste statements that are called later on. With `dbGetQuery(statement)` from the R SQL packages this works just fine (when statement is a character vector). 2.) Plus I wonder what the use of the newcol column(s) is in our example. Why don't you use `lag()`? Is it because `faithful is not a ts?`

Comment: I didn't use `lag` simply because I couldn't get it to work with a `data.frame` but no doubt you'll do better!